# MD5 hexdigest verification with a string

Tags: perl

I am having a problem comparing the result from the `file_md5_hex( $dir )` subroutine with a string read from a file.
When I print they are both the same, but when I compare them in a if I get all the time equal regardless of the value they have.

```
elsif ( -f $dir )
{
 if($dir ne "$mydir.txt" && $dir ne "log.txt")
 {
  my $filename = "$mydir.txt";
  open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
  print FILE "$dir -> ";
  while (my $row = <$fh>)
  {
   chomp($row);
   if($row eq $dir)
     {
      my $hash = <$fh>;
      chomp($hash);
      print FILE "$hash = ";
      break;
     }
  }
  close $fh;
   my $md5 = file_md5_hex( $dir );
   print FILE "$md5\n";
   print FILE ref($md5);
   print FILE ref($hash);
   if( $md5 eq $hash )
   {
     print FILE "Hash ok!\n";
     }
   else
   {
     print FILERESULT "In $mydir file $dir is corrupted. Correct is $hash, calculated is $md5\n";
     print FILE "Hash Nok!\n";
   }
 }
}
```

In the log file I see that the 2 values `$md5` and `$hash` are the same or different (depending on the case I simulate) but when I verify the program sees them as always equal. I think there might be a problem with the types of data but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You increase your chances of helping your self and getting helpful answers by minimizing your program to the minimal version which still shows your problem:, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 2):

`use strict` to detect errors with variable names and scopes.
$hash is not defined on `if( $md5 eq $hash )` because `my $hash = <$fh>;` is out of scope.
Declare `my $hash` before `while (my $row = <$fh>)` and set the value with `$hash = <$fh>;`

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html